# Python - Solving command line error for Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I am trying to use Tweepy to stream Tweets from a developer API. I want to convert this into an SQLite database file.

However, I am getting an unusual error that links to the Tweepy libraries on my computer. I am using Python 3.6.7 (if that might have something to do with it).

Please let me know if you require more information.

In Windows 10 command line:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\CONFIDENTIAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "C:\Users\CONFIDENTIAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\CONFIDENTIAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 293, in _run
> self.listener.on_exception(exception)
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'on_exception'

Comment: Would it be possible to get the snippet of code causing the error. Otherwise, this is just a generic error. It is just saying that whatever you are passing in is an `int`; therefore, it obviously does not have the attrribute `on_exception`

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know what part of my code is causing the error as it isn't specified in the command line. It seems to be focusing on the .py files in the Python and Tweepy libraries. However, I noticed I get no result or error after I remove this code `stream.filter(track=['keyword'], async=True)`

Answer (score 0):

When initializing `tweepy.Stream`, you're passing an integer for the `listener` parameter, rather than an instance of `tweepy.StreamListener`. See [the Streaming with Tweepy section of Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.10.0/streaming_how_to.html).